# What is the limit of .NET Cache keys I can store?

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I want to store up to 500 cache keys (one per user) using System.Web.Caching. The cached value wouldn't exceed an 11 character string (ie. 'Los Angeles')

```
string key = "Location" + userName;
string location = GetUsersLocation();
Cache.Insert(key, location);
```

Does this surpass the limitations of .NET caching or would this technique go against best practices?

Comment: I'd be amazed if a few kilobytes of data surpassed the limitations of System.Web.Caching..

Comment: I'm not sure what the limit is, but I store thousands of keys with hundreds of megabytes in the cache.

Comment: yeah, it wouldn't be more than 20KB. The question is really about the number of keys and the best practice for this scenario

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/post/1199949.aspx for specific numbers. Yes, this would (broadly) be considered a fine practice both for number of keys and the size of data stored.

Comment: why dont you use memorycache...

Comment: terry 'm not aware. What do you think the advantages it has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cache limit depends on the available system memory and on your worker process if running in 64 bits or 32 bits.
you will be able to use much more memory if running in 64 bits.
ASP.NET Cache will engage garbage collections and starts dropping cache when a w3wp process memory usage is greater than or equal to about 80% of the worker process memory limit.The worker process memory limit can be set in machine.config for aspnet_wp.exe, or in the IIS metabase for w3wp.exe.

Comment: is it Server memory or client side Memory?